# How to create histogram plot in ggplot2 without data frame?

Tags: r, ggplot2

I am plotting two histograms in R by using the following code.

```
x1<-rnorm(100)
x2<-rnorm(50)  
h1<-hist(x1)
h2<-hist(x2)
plot(h1, col=rgb(0,0,1,.25), xlim=c(-4,4), ylim=c(0,0.6), main="", xlab="Index", ylab="Percent",freq = FALSE)
plot(h2, col=rgb(1,0,0,.25), xlim=c(-4,4), ylim=c(0,0.6), main="", xlab="Index", ylab="Percent",freq = FALSE,add=TRUE)
legend("topright", c("H1", "H2"), fill=c(rgb(0,0,1,.25),rgb(1,0,0,.25)))
```

The code produces the following output.
[image]

I need a visually good looking (or stylistic) version of the above plot. I want to use ggplot2. I am looking for something like [this (see Change fill colors section)](http://www.sthda.com/english/wiki/ggplot2-histogram-plot-quick-start-guide-r-software-and-data-visualization). However, I think, ggplot2 only works with data frames. I do not have data frames in this case. Hence, how can I create good looking histogram plot in ggplot2? Please let me know. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Yes, ggplot works on data frames. Any reason why you can't just make a data frame from that data?

Comment: Just in case the rhetorical nature of @camille 's question was lost on you.  You can and should create a data.frame from your data.

Comment: @dww: Please provide me an example.

Comment: @BeautifulMind - sorry, I didnt realize doing that step would be the challenge. Added an answer to show how.

Answer (score 1):

You can (and should) put your data into a `data.frame` if you want to use `ggplot`.  Ideally for `ggplot`, the `data.frame` should be in long format. Here's a simple example:

```
df1 = rbind(data.frame(grp='x1', x=x1), data.frame(grp='x2', x=x2))

ggplot(df1, aes(x, fill=grp)) + 
  geom_histogram(color='black', alpha=0.5)
```

There are lots of options to change the appearnce how you like. If you want to have the histograms stacked or grouped, or shown as percent versus count, or as densities etc., you will find many resources in previous questions showing how to implement each of those options.

[image]